# Tweepy API: get full text of tweet (>140 characters)

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I am unable to get the entire text of a tweet - every tweet is limited to only 140 characters, afterwards ends in "..."

I am already using full_text and tweet_mode='extended', still it does not yet work

```
tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,q=search_words,lang="en",since=date_since,until=date_until, tweet_mode='extended').items(10)

users_locs = [[tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.user.location,tweet.full_text, tweet.created_at] for tweet in tweets]

tweet_text = pd.DataFrame(data=users_locs,columns=['user', 'location','text','date'])
```

Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the version of Tweepy you are using and update to the latest.

I used three different (including yours) ways and I am able to get the "full_text" with "tweet_mode='extended'" with Tweepy 3.9.0

The methods I used are:

```
status_list = api.statuses_lookup(list_of_ids, trim_user=False, tweet_mode="extended")
tweet_status = api.get_status(single_id, tweet_mode="extended")
tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,q=search_words,lang="en",since=date_since,until=date_until, tweet_mode='extended').items(10)
```

And got the full_text in every one of them.